# Is there any way to increase the number of items I can hold?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

I've been playing Pocket Camp for about an hour or so and I'm already holding 100/100 items and I can't hold anymore?!

So I went to the item screen and it clearly says 100/100 but I don't see anywhere that allows me to hold more items.

Can I craft a bag that increases this limit or is there something I need to build in my park to store the items?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can increase your inventory size by opening your inventory, going to the Items tab, scrolling down and pressing the "+" at the bottom of your item list.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah, I missed the stupid + sign at the bottom. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you keep leveling up, you'll get more inventory space eventually. It's not much though. It's like 5 more inventory space every couple of levels.

Or you can pay tickets for it.

Comment: +1 for an additional way to gain inventory slots that wasn't mentioned in accepted answer